# Fastest way to add column at runtime that is same for all rows in AWS Athena / SQL

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm using aws athena to create a table. When creating this table, I want to add the creation date (like 2019-09-05) as a column to the table. What is the fastest way to do it?

Here are some of the possible ways (Note: current_date is a presto function, more details here: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html):

```
1. select [
     ...,
     current_date
   ]
   from a;

2. with variables as (select current_date as date_created)
   select [
     ...,
     variables.date_created
   ]
   from a, variables;

3. Using python to replace the expression
   select [
     ...,
     <REPLACE_ME>
   ]
   from a;

   # In python
   s = query.replace("<REPLACE_ME>", datetime.now())
   # run query in python
```

Method 3 will be fastest as I can guess, but is it possible only using sql? Method 2 creates a cartesian product, so this might be a problem if we want to add multiple columns and Method 1 executes the function for each row.

So, what is the fastest and best way? Since I am using athena which is based on presto, there is no way to use variables afaik. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is the best:

```
SELECT <all other columns>, current_date
FROM ...
```

`current_date` will be executed once. Its value is inlined during query planning. Same happens for any other deterministic scalar expression.

Comment: If it is a "case" statement that only depends on current date (like if today's day of month is greater than 10...), then also will it be executed only once?

Comment: Yes (the code is here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/9913d903c3bd8039b0d7ce736cb928c229d4d127/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/sql/planner/ExpressionInterpreter.java#L445-L484)